# Die Bedeutung der Lokaladverbien "drüben" und "hüben"

Tags: adverb

Ich bin Italiener und oft benutze das Wörterbuch, aber ich kann die Bedeutung der Lokaladverbien "*drüben*" und "*hüben*" nicht verstehen. Jemand könnte mir mit eigenen Beispielsätze helfen

Comment: Ich bin Deutscher in Italien, mein Deutsch kommt von meiner Oma die mit uns wohnte, von 15 Jahren Deutscher Schule, und einem Jahr Uni in Deutschland. _Hüben_ hatte ich bis heute noch _nie_ weder gehört noch gelesen.

Comment: @WalterTross: Das ist unerheblich; das Wort gibt's dennoch. Und btw: 'hatte ich bis heute weder gehört noch gelesen' oder 'noch nie gehört oder gelesen', aber nicht 'noch nie weder gehört, noch gelesen', letzteres ist doppelte Verneinung.

Comment: @userunknown danke für die Verbesserung. Ich wollte jedenfalls nicht behaupten, dass es das Wort nicht gibt, sondern dem OP ein Maß für dessen Seltenheit liefern.

Comment: @WalterTross: Lustigte Koinzidenz: Just wo ich den Tab schließen will, sagt einer der Sportreporter in der ARD-Schlusskonferenz etwas wie 'keine Chancen, hüben wie drüben'.

Comment: Vielleicht hat er ja hier mitgelesen ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*hüben* wird meistens in der Redewendung *hüben wie/und drüben* verwendet. Dass *hüben* nur in einem Kontext mit *drüben* vorkommt, sagt auch duden.de (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hueben). Dort steht "Adverb; nur in Opposition zu »drüben« gebraucht". Ich hatte das Wort *hüben* nicht einmal gehört, bis ich ca. 16 war, und es befindet sich immer noch nicht in meinem aktiven Wortschatz.

*drüben* hingegen bezeichnet eine andere "Seite" (eines irgendwie abgegrenzten Ortes), wie tofro andeutet. Es kann aber auch die Seite sein, auf der man selbst ist, wenn sie mit einer anderen Seite kontrastiert (dann meist *hier drüben*), z.B. in einem Satz wie *Bei dir im Wohnzimmer mag alles trocken sein, aber **hier drüben** in der Küche ist der ganze Boden nass.*

Edit:

*hier drüben* ist ein weitaus gängigerer Ausdruck als *hüben*. Ich habe nicht genügend Renomee, um den Kommentar direkt zu beantworten, aber Deinen Beispielsatz hätte ich *Das Auto hier ist sauber. Was mit dem anderen ist, weiß ich nicht.* oder ähnlich formuliert. *Das Auto hier drüben ist sauber.* geht am besten, wenn der Adressat, an den die Aussage gerichtet wird, nicht auch direkt neben dem Auto steht.

Comment: Im hessischen Dialekt kommt *hüben* durchaus auch einzeln vor, z.B. ist das Stadtzentrum von Frankfurt "hibbdebach" (diesseits des Flusses), Sachsenhausen dagegen "dribbdebach" (jenseits des Flusses).

Comment: @dirkt Nein, der Main wird in Frankfurt als *Bach* bezeichnet? Wie geil =D

Answer (score 3):

Wie schon in anderen Antworten bemerkt kommt *hüben ([Duden Eintrag](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hueben))* praktisch nur in Redewendungen als Gegensatz zu *[drüben](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drueben)* vor und bedeutet in diesem Zusammenhang "auf dieser Seite".

Gebräuchlicher ist es, einfach *[hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hier)* zu verwenden, oder auch *hier drüben*.

In südlicheren Gegenden wie zum Beispiel in Bayern oder hier in Österreich wird der Gegensatz zu *drüben* üblicherweise als *[herüben](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herueben)* ausgedrückt, und dieses Wort ist auch noch sehr lebendig.

Answer (score 1):

Nachdem nach Beispielen gefragt wurde:

Ich stehe am Fluss und schaue auf die andre Seite. 
Ich bin *hüben*, die andren *drüben*.
Wenn ich vom *Hüben* zum *Drüben* will, brauche ich ein Boot oder muss schwimmen.
(Funktioniert auch mit Grenzen, Mauern, Zäunen, dann natürlich ohne Boot....)

Comment: hoffentlich habe ich verstanden, Z.b. "Das Auto hüben ist sauber, drüben weiß ich nicht", ist der Satz korrekt?

Comment: Der Satz ist grammatikalisch richtig. Es fehlt allerdings der Kontext, der die Grenze zwischen hüben und drüben beschreibt. In der modernen Sprache wird die Paarung nur noch selten benutzt, wenn dann in solchen Zusammenhängen wie "Der Ärmelkanal trennt Europa nicht mehr richtig -  Hüben wie drüben haben die Länder dieselben Probleme".

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde sagen, "hüben" ist eine kreative und freizügige Wortschöpfung, die ihren Sinn allein durch die Harmonie des Gleichklangs "hüben" vs. "drüben" findet.
So ähnlich wie "Hinz und Kunz" oder "mit allem Zip und Zap" - sinnfrei, aber klingt nett und wird so übernommen, weitergegeben und so geläufig.

Sicher gibt's einen Fachbegriff dafür - ist mir aber nicht bekannt - und gibt's sicher auch in anderen Sprachen.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Gibt es für die Aussage "ich würde sagen" auch eine nachvollziehbare Quelle? Den Fachbegriff rauszusuchen und in der Antwort zu benutzen - das würde die Antwort einer Antwort näher bringen. Und dann bleibt noch: Welches Wissen, das so in den anderen Antworten fehlt, ist in dieser enthalten? FF

Answer (score -1):

hier und dort
here and there
hüben and drüben

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hueben

There you go:

Hüben = hier oder diesseits
and
Drüben = dort oder jenseits