# What was the meaning of adverb "üben"?

Tags: etymology, archaism

I don't mean "üben" as in "exercise".

I mean "üben" as in da dr**üben**. I suppose, for the contraction *drüben* made from *darüben* to appear, there should have existed a word *üben*. If so, what was it's meaning? Moreover, what was its connection with *oben* or *hinten*? What I mean:

- hinter -- hinten
- vor --  vorne
- über -- ? üben ?
  -- ? ober ? --> oben

I searched in Wikipedia, but there the page for *darüben* does not exists, [as is provided here](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/dr%C3%BCben).

Comment: Have you checked for *darüber*? This word exists.

Comment: I doubt, that the word is dated; the reason for its obscureness is its colloquial character (i wouold consider that as pretty constant); it may even belong to a dialect.. A source, where you found it, would be helpful.

Comment: Meaning discussed here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28287/die-bedeutung-der-lokaladverbien-dr%C3%BCben-und-h%C3%BCben

Comment: There is _hüben_, for example in _hüben und drüben_, but no _üben_

Answer (score 13):

The word that describes a movement across (over) a border, towards the speaker is:

- **herüber:**
  over, across, ... (towards the speaker)

And in southern parts of Germany and in Austria there is also a very similar word that doesn't describe the movement, but the result of this movement:

- **herüben:**
  over here, on this side

This word is rarely used in northern parts of Germany, but very common in southern parts (Bavaria, Austria). Here are examples for the usage of both words:

- Gestern kam Kurt zu uns **herüber.** (Kurt came over to us yesterday.)
  Kurt moved towards us. When he did, he crossed some kind of border, which can be a river, the border of the township, maybe the doorsill, or maybe just the imaginary boundary around a group of people.
- Heute ist Kurt bei uns **herüben.** (Kurt is with us today.)
  Today Kurt is with us. In the past he stepped over some kind of border (which in most cases is an imaginary border) towards us, and now he is within our areal. (He is not "over there", he is "with us".)

For this word *herüben* also exists an old shorthand version: *hüben.* The words *hüben* and *herüben* both mean: on this side of the border (whatever the border may be).

So, if you have a word that describes the state of being on this side of a border (in Latin: *cis*), you also need a word for being on the other side of the border (in Latin *trans*). It would seem logical if this word was *hinüben* (because the movement across a border away from the speaker is: *hinüber*), but language is not always logical. In fact the word was: *darüben.*

So, the old word *darüben* meant the opposite of *herüben*, and is also was transformed into a shorthand version, which is *drüben.*

- Long versions: herüben, darüben
- Short versions: hüben, drüben

But from the pair *herüben - hüben* only the long version survived, and it only survived where it was created: in the southern parts of the german speaking region.

On the other hand, from the pair *darüben - drüben* the short version survived, and it even spread across all regions where you speak German. The long version *darüben* became completely extinct.

Btw: The word *hüben* (short of *herüben*) found a way to survive, but only in one fixed phrase which is *hüben und drüben* or *hüben wie drüben*. It means "on both sides".

As far as I found out, the naked preposition or adverb *üben* without any prefix never existed. Only *herüben* and *drüben* exist. (*hüben* exists as part of a phrase, and *darüben* maybe existed, but became completely extinct). But from the meaning of the existing words you can conclude that *üben* (if it existed) would mean "being on one side of a border".

Comment: Do you have a reference for darüben? Pfeifer seems to say that this is not the original: "An das seit dem 13. Jh. bezeugte drüber schließt sich im Nhd. (nachweisbar erst Anfang des 18. Jhs.) die Lagebezeichnung drüben an (daneben im 18. Jh. gelegentlich darüben, daüben wohl als hyperkorrekte, nicht sprachübliche Bildungen)." https://www.dwds.de/wb/dr%C3%BCben

Comment: Die Formulierung "hüben wie drüben" ist sogar mir als Berliner geläufig.

Comment: Der Ausdruck *hüben wie Drüben* ist ja auch wegen der Deutschen Trennung oft gebraucht worden, die mit der Mauer sehr Präsent war in Berlin. Überigens sollte man wegen wegen dem *h* mal überlegen ob nicht ein Zusammenhang zu *hyper* bzw. *hypo* besteht, eigentlich offensichtlich, oder ne?

Comment: Mir ist bei vectorys Etymogeleien (hüben - hyper) nie ganz klar, ob er diesen Unsinn ernst meint oder einfach nur trollt. Seit wann korrespondiert ein germanisches anlautendes "h" zu einem griechischen? (Stichwort: germanische Lautverschiebung.)

Comment: @Uwe: Ich denke, er weiß es einfach nicht besser und meint es gar nicht böse. Alle Menschen halten hie und da zufällige Ähnlichkeiten für ganz offensichtlich systematische Zusammenhänge. Wenn man damit recht hatte, konnte das unseren Vorfahren schon mal das Leben retten. Wenn man sich geirrt hat, blieb man im schlimmsten Fall hungrig. Daher ist ist die Tendenz falscher Schlüsse zu ziehen in uns allen drin. Dagegen hilft nur sich bewusst zu machen, dass einem das jederzeit passieren kann, und lieber mal den Mund zu halten wenn man's nicht ganz genau weis. Das muss man aber auch erst mal lernen.

Answer (score 5):

If *drüben* is to be analysed parallel to *dr+innen, dr+außen, dr+oben* as *dr+üben*, this would make *üben* a [cranberry morpheme](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Cranberry_morpheme). Just like the *cran* in *cranberry*, it does not occur independently and cannot be assigned a meaning.

As far as etymology is concerned, Pfeifer [says](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dr%C3%BCben):

> **drüben** Adv. ‘auf der anderen Seite, jenseits’. In zusammengesetzten Ortsadverbien mit vokalisch anlautendem zweitem Glied vorkommendes mhd. nhd. *dar-* […] wird im Mhd. oft zu *der-, dir-* abgeschwächt bzw. (in vielen Fällen schon frühmhd.) zu *dr-* synkopiert; daher nhd. *dran, drauf, drüber* […] An das seit dem 13. Jh. bezeugte *drüber* schließt sich im Nhd. (nachweisbar erst Anfang des 18. Jhs.) die Lagebezeichnung *drüben* an (daneben im 18. Jh. gelegentlich *darüben, daüben* wohl als hyperkorrekte, nicht sprachübliche Bildungen).
>
> […]
>
> Einfaches *üben* Adv. ‘jenseits’ als Entsprechung zu ↗über (s. d.) findet sich nur vereinzelt in obd. Mundarten (z. B. bei Frisch 1741 gebucht) […]

DWB says about [üben](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=23,72,43):

> *der gebrauch war zu allen zeiten landschaftlich beschränkt. allgemein gebraucht dagegen die compp. z. b.* hüben, herüben, drüben

So *üben* was never in general use; only the compounds *drüben, herüben, hüben* were. Note that, in present-day German, *hüben* is mostly used together with *drüben*, e.g. as *hüben und drüben*.

*Drüben* by itself, on the other hand, is in general use, for instance in *da, dort drüben* or *drüben* plus a prepositional phrase, such as *drüben in den USA*.

As Hubert already mentioned, *herüben* is not common outside of Bavaria and Austria.

Comment: Erzähle mehr über *dr+osten.* Ich habe das Wort *»drosten«* weder jemals gehört oder gelesen, noch in irgend einem Wörterbuch gefunden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Hört man in letzter Zeit oft beim NDR.

Comment: Aha. Und was soll *drosten* bedeuten? Ich vermute mal "östlich vom Sprecher"? Viel interessanter: Bei welchen Gelegenheiten verwendet man dieses Wort? Angenommen ich wäre Landwirt und hätte ein Maisfeld das östlich vom Bauernhaus liegt. Kann man dann sagen »der Mais wächst drosten«? Oder ist das wieder etwas, das mit der Ex-DDR zu tun hat? (Ihr Deutschen schient da ja noch immer eine große Sache draus zu machen.)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Sorry, nur ein Scherz. Die Krise hinterlässt auch bei mir Spuren. https://www.ndr.de/nachrichten/info/podcast4684.html

Comment: Bin ja froh, daß überhaupt jemand so genau mitliest.

Comment: It's easy to find examples of *hier drüben* = "over here". I gather that, as with "over", the distance is relative to the listener and not the speaker. I gather also that *hüben* is dying out in spoken German; at best it only appears in some fixed phrases involving *drüben*.